# Создание резервной копии базы данных

Tags: qt, sqlite

Есть база данных (**SQLite3** с одной таблицей) для хранения логиннов и паролей.
Есть тривиальный интерфейс, написанный на Qt, для добавления/редактирования/удаления строк данных в БД.
Добавление и редактирование возможно только при вызове модального диалогового окна (реализовано, через QDataWidgetMapper).

Собственно, суть вопроса: **как реализовать резервное копирование базы данных (например, что бы при запуске приложения создавалась копия БД)? Опишите алгоритм действий и какие функции для этого нужны**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**АПДЕЙТ:**
Подключил исходники sqlite3.h sqlite3.c в проект.
Написал функцию для бэкапа:

```
int DataBase::backupDb()
{
    int rc;
    QVariant vHND = m_db.driver()->handle();
    if(vHND.isValid() && qstrcmp(vHND.typeName(), "sqlite3*") == 0)
    {
        sqlite3 * handle = *static_cast<sqlite3 **>(vHND.data());
        sqlite3 *pDb = handle;

        QByteArray array = DATABASE_NAME.toLocal8Bit();
        const char * zFilename = array.data();

        sqlite3 *pFile;
        sqlite3_backup *pBackup;

        rc = sqlite3_open(zFilename, &pFile);
        if( rc==SQLITE_OK )
        {
            pBackup = sqlite3_backup_init(pFile, "main", pDb, "main");
            if( pBackup )
            {
                rc = sqlite3_backup_step(pBackup, -1);
                (void)sqlite3_backup_finish(pBackup);
            }
            rc = sqlite3_errcode(pFile);
        }
        (void)sqlite3_close(pFile);
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Но, на строке: `rc = sqlite3_backup_step(pBackup, -1);`
Вылетает ошибка: "segmentation fault". 
ЧТО НЕ ТАК?

п.с. функцию использую при запуске приложения, после соединения с БД.

Comment: sqlite -- файлик, поэтому можете просто делать его копию и в названии указывать текущую дату и время

Comment: @gil9red а есть ли более "техничные" способы?

Comment: гуглится на это: https://sqlite.org/backup.html

Comment: про segmentation fault лучше отдельный вопрос задать. С полным, но минимальным примером кода. [mcve]

Comment: @jfs ошибка возникала из-за конфликта с встроенным в Qt драйвером БД.

Comment: @AndreyAHAHAC если вы нашли причину для segfault, то опубликуйте в виде своего ответа, чтобы другим с похожей проблемой помочь в будущем. [Это явно приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)